# How to separate decoded timestamps from just float numbers in python?

Tags: python-3.x, timestamp

I have an object in my API, and this object have two types of variables: ***timestamps*** and ***float numbers***.  I have created a method that extracts all requested variables from the object and tries converting received data from ***timestamp*** to actual date. The problem occurred when this method started treating float numbers as timestamps and began decoding float numbers.

```
try:
    date_formatted = self.utils.convert_from_date_to_timestamp(
        api_values[row_index], "%d-%m-%Y"
    )
    cell_value.text = date_formatted
except:
    cell_value.text = str(api_values[row_index])
```

Is there a way I can separate float numbers from actual timestamps? This is an example of timestamp: `1653898192`. And this is just a float number: `100.00000`, but it's getting decoded to `1/1/1970`. I don't want it to happen, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What does your data look like? does it have any labels?

Comment: in your example, both `1653898192.` and `100.00000` are valid timestamps (assuming Unix time in seconds since 1970-01-01 Z). So basically, there's no way to tell if one is "just a floating point number" - do you have additional information?